# Can I directly Upgrade Laravel 5.5 to Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel-5, upgrade, laravel-6

I need to upgrade my website from Laravel 5.5 to Laravel 6.

Can I directly upgrade to it?

`Laravel 5.5 => Laravel 6.x`

Or

Do I need to upgrade step by step?

`Laravel 5.5 => Laravel 5.6 => Laravel 5.7 => Laravel 5.8 => Laravel 6.x`

Or

Let me know any other optimum way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as per laravel version veries please confirm that your php version compatible or not.

Comment: I can update my PHP version so no issue regarding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel 5.5 => Laravel 5.6 => Laravel 5.7 => Laravel 5.8 => Laravel 6.x

That is the way because Laravel has the upgrade documentations only for one lower version.

If you do a direct upgrade to 6.x, there are high chances that you miss some of the internal version changes in your code which will cause you a lot of headaches to resolve and locate later.

If you go step by step, you will be able to test your application or api after each upgrade and resolve the issue and take the help of individual upgrade documentation.

Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes. Thanks

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you so that we may close this thread on stackoverflow..thanks!